# jqGrid jsonp:false OR avoid callback appending to URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am using codeigniter with jqgrid to create a grid. It was working fine with jquery 1.3 until I updated jquery to 1.5.

**Problem**

I noticed a callback parameter appending to URL in all ajax calls and causing 404. All request URI are formatted in compliance of codeigniter standards(avoid using query strings) so I can understand 404.

jquery 1.5 documentation tells to do the following

{jsonp: false, jsonPCallback : "functionname"}

this stripped "?callback=jqueryXXXXXXXX_XXXXXX" from URI but jqGrid stops processing the data and hence resulting in empty grid.

**What I want?**

No query string should be attached to "url" and data should still be processed.

**Example**

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        url:'/healthcare/user/weight/get_full_report_data',
        datatype: "json",
        postData: {selected_week_id: "1"},
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Rank', 'Team', 'Total', 'Starting Weight', 'Lost(lbs)', 'Lost %', 'Department', 'Location', 'Reference1',
            'Reference2']
)}
)};

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Which web browser do you use in your tests? Look at [the demo](file://storage-5/public/Documents/Oleg/TEMA/1.0/VerticalHeaders/google-tables1.htm) which I prepared for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317646/jqgrid-returns-blank-cells/4326986#4326986). It works on in all web browsers excepting IE9. Probably the example will help you. Is the server which you call is accassible from the internet? If it is so could you post the url and the full demo which not more work after updating to the jQuery 1.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and, after too much googling, I ended up it was because of the jquery.validate.min.js, that forced jsonp calls.

No more problems with the new version of JQuery Validation 1.8

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/