# jqgrid json reader for arcgis server query results

Tags: json, jqgrid, jsonp, arcgis

what kind of json reader I need to plot data like [these](http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/4/query?text=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&objectIds=&where=1=1&time=&returnCountOnly=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=false&maxAllowableOffset=&outSR=&outFields=ObjectID,%20NAME,%20STATE_NAME,%20CNTY_FIPS&f=pjson) in a jqgrid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have strange questions and all about the `jsonReader`. In the current case you can use

```js
jsonReader: {
    root: 'features',
    repeatitems: false
}
```

to read the data. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user781065_.htm) shows how the results can looks like:

[image]

**UPDATED**: How I understand, what you want really to do is to call some *external* URL which provide you back the JSON. Standard Ajax request can't be done to another server because of security reasons (see [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). Fortunately the server `sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS` supports JSONP requests. So to fill the grid with external data you can use the following code

```js
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: 'http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/4/query',
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    postData: $.param({
        where: "1=1",
        returnGeometry: false,
        outFields: "ObjectID,NAME,STATE_NAME,CNTY_FIPS",
        f: "json"
    }),
    colModel: [
        {name: 'ObjectID', label: 'ID', width: 60, jsonmap: 'attributes.ObjectID'},
        {name: 'NAME', label: 'Name', width: 150, jsonmap: 'attributes.NAME'},
        {name: 'STATE_NAME', label: 'State', width: 120, jsonmap: 'attributes.STATE_NAME'},
        {name: 'CNTY_FIPS', label: 'FIPS', width: 60, jsonmap: 'attributes.CNTY_FIPS'}
    ],
    toppager: true,
    jsonReader: {
        root: 'features',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    loadonce: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    height: 'auto'
});
```

See the new demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user781065_jsonp.htm).

**UPDATED 2**: To be able to use local searching/filtering one should modify the above code. It's better to replace `postData` which one sees above to the following parameters

```
ajaxGridOptions: { cache: true },
prmNames: {search: null, nd: null, sort: null, rows: null, order: null, page: null},
postData: {
    where: "1=1",
    returnGeometry: false,
    outFields: "ObjectID,NAME,STATE_NAME,CNTY_FIPS",
    f: "json"
}
```

See [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user781065_jsonp_.htm) where `filterToolbar` works.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. 
My job is about GIS and web development, an important part of this is to render geospatial data in a grid, so I think my questions are not so strange... Probably I have to read the json reader documentation more accurate. Thank you again

Comment: @user781065: You are welcome! I forgot to mention, that I used additionally `jsonmap` like `jsonmap: 'attributes.NAME'` in the answer. The official documentation you can find [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data). With respect of [jsonReader as function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function) one can read practically any JSON input. Additionally sometimes are helpful to use `beforeProcessing` callback. If the problem is solved you can mark the answer as "accepted".

Comment: Oleg, did you try with the url I supplied in the first post?
Using it the grid is always empty and firebug return status 200 OK for the request, but in red color...

Comment: @user781065: Which `URL` you mean? Which your post you mean? This one or your first question on the stackoverflow? In my demo I used the exact copy of your data.

Comment: Hi Oleg, look at the demo here:
dl.dropbox.com/u/1070973/jqgrid_reader/index2.html

Comment: @user781065: What you want can't be done with JSON requests, but one can use JSONP in the case. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you Oleg, I was managing to write a proxy in the meantime, but jsonp is a better solution.

Comment: Hi, I need a little help to understand how to add a filterToolbar to this grid. I tried this: 

`$("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user781065: What exactly "not works"? Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` so that searching will be local even if you use remote data? You should post more full description about your problem in new question.

Comment: Hi Oleg, datatype is jsonp (like in the example) and loadonce is set to true, but when I type inside a filter field nothing happens.

Comment: @user781065: I analysed the problem. One should change `postData` parameter how I described in **UPDATED 2** of my answer.