# jqGrid crossdomain request providing custom callback name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a cross domain request that requires the callback to be specified as follows

```
http://<server>:<port>/../../abc?_callback=<callbackName>
```

With jqGrid, I am not sure how to go about enabling this. jqGrid is a wrapper for the $.ajax call which takes in the url and also allows you to specify the crossdomain properties. My current configuration which provides the right response:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
url:'<sample cross domain URL>',
callback: 'callme',
mtype: 'GET',
crossDomain: true,
datatype: 'jsonp',
jsonp: true,
cache: true,
....... // other grid properties to load the layout for this dynamic data. 

)};
```

The line "callback: 'callme'" does not seem to work as firebug shows a default callback value assigned for the request. However this callback is specified as

```
<sample URL>?callback=jqueryXXX...X 

instead of

<sampleURL>?_callback=callme
```

Is there any way in which jqGrid allows you to specify custom callback names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main error is that you use some options which not exist in jqGrid. You use `callback`, `crossDomain`, `jsonp` and `cache` which are supported options of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but there are no such options in jqGrid.

I hope that you find answer on your question after examining of demos from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588051/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326986/315935).

Answer (score 0):

I had also some problems with jqgrid and a remote URL (cross domain).
To solve them, I have used a php page on my domain : cross-domain.php that takes a GET parameter :

Here is the content of the php page :

```
<?php
    print(file_get_contents($_GET['url']));
?>
```

Thus, to fill a jqgrid with such an URL :

```
jQuery("#jqgrid_table_id").jqGrid({
    url : <?php print("'cross-domaine.php?url=" . urlencode('http://www.example.com/my_json_webservice.php') . "'"); ?>,
    ...
});
```

It works great, and of course it can be done with any server language.

And you don't have to worry about [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issues.