# how to populate jqGrid table using json

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am creating a jqgrid from the json string "http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/John.txt"

I wrote the JavaScript similar to "http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/John.htm" and **url** 
pointing to the john.txt file.

It is giving me a table without any rows. please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Demonstration how to read simple JSON text</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                $('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
                    url: 'http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/John.txt',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'col1' },
                        { name: 'col2' },
                        { name: 'col3' }
                    ],
                    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                    height: 'auto'
                });
                });
        //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="jqgrid"><tr><td/></tr></table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is what my code is...
and this is what I am getting

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=vqps1x&s=6

Comment: You should post *your exact code*. [My old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/John.htm) works. So to be able to understand your problem one should know *your code*.

Comment: please find the code I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be careful with the usage of `url` in the form "http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/John.txt″ because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions. You can use ajax requests only for data from the same web site. So to prevent this you should use **url** without **protocol, domain and port prefix**. Here since the data you are trying to access is from another domain you are unable to pass it directly to the `url` parameter. The solution for this is that you have to use your own **json** data to assign or your own domain **url** to get the data from. Or you could set a local variable with the **json** data and assign it to the **jqGrid**

Comment: thank you mann.. sorry for late comments.. its bcs json is in different domain. When I put them in same domain it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because, you are making an ajax request for a resource which is in another domain.

Try this, save the given below data to a file John.txt and change your URL to point this

`url: 'John.txt'`,

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 12,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "col1": "cell11",
            "col2": "cell12",
            "col3": "cell13" 
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "col1": "cell21",
            "col2": "cell22",
            "col3": "cell23" 
        } 
    ] 
}
```